# Making NodeJS app publicly available in Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am building an azure template (https://github.com/kevinday/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/augur-on-ubuntu/azuredeploy.json) that will run a nodejs app in an Ubuntu VM.

```
npm start

augur-ui@2.0.0 start /root/augur
http-server ./build -c-1 -p $PORT

Starting up http-server, serving ./build
Available on:
http://127.0.0.1:true
http://10.0.0.4:true
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
```

I'd like to expose http traffic to the dns name that I have configured, http://dnsname.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com.

I've seen documentation suggesting configuring and endpoint in the portal, though I no longer see this option. Can someone point me in the right direction for how to modify my template in order to configure this endpoint correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an inbound rule in the network security group to allow traffic on port 80.

```
{
  "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
  "name": "[variables('networkSecurityGroupName')]",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "properties": {
    "securityRules": [
      {
        "name": "httpRule",
        "properties": {
          "description": "httpRule",
          "protocol": "Tcp",
          "sourcePortRange": "*",
          "destinationPortRange": "80",
          "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
          "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
          "access": "Allow",
          "priority": 110,
          "direction": "Inbound"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

A complete sample of template with NSG and Inbound rule is available here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/101-security-group-create/azuredeploy.json

For more about Azure Network Security Groups, see: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-nsg/

Answer (score 0):

As I known, you can try to create the `web-rule` of NSG-FrontEnd for to allow HTTP traffic to the FrontEnd subnet.

Please see the document [How to create NSGs using a template](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-create-nsg-arm-template/) to know how to do it using ARM.

Here is a sample ARM template snippet.

```
"apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
"type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
"name": "[parameters('frontEndNSGName')]",
"location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
"tags": {
  "displayName": "NSG - Front End"
},
"properties": {
  "securityRules": [
    {
        "name": "web-rule",
        "properties": {
        "description": "Allow WEB",
        "protocol": "Tcp",
        "sourcePortRange": "*",
        "destinationPortRange": "80",
        "sourceAddressPrefix": "Internet",
        "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
        "access": "Allow",
        "priority": 101,
        "direction": "Inbound"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```